# Three riddles of a common (and repetitive) format

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking, language

1. What do you call it when a historically discredited means of contraceptive is vindicated by new research?
2. *I* was just looking over my son's book report on speed reading strategies; what are *you* doing right now?
3. What is this? The forums have been overwhelmed with hatemail after a dev criticized the tone of a negative review.

Once you figure out the answer to one of these riddles, the others should be much easier.

Regarding these riddles' theme, my hint for you is but one word, repeated for emphasis:

> Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo

---

Riddles solved! Here are the canonical answers I had in mind (adequate substitutes figured out by users semi-collaboratively):

> [Buffalo hint.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)
>  1. [A failure to replicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis) [a failure to replicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis) [a failure to replicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_reproduction).
>  2. Reading about reading about reading about reading.
>  3. Complaining about complaining about complaining.

Comment: Your three riddles form a repeated repetitive format!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Partial</del> Now hopefully complete answer:

2:

> Skimming through skimming (skimming is a speed reading strategy, and skimming is a way to look something over).

3:

> Complaint complaint complaints (*complaints* about the dev's *complaint* about *complaints*)—could also just be "complaint complaints" if they're all two words.

<del>Not sure about #1.  Can't come up with anything that really makes sense.</del>

1: (based on [villasv's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/111262/70360) and the hint in the comments on this answer)

> Withdrawal of withdrawal of withdrawal—that is, the earlier withdrawal of (recommendation against) the withdrawal (AKA "pulling out") method of contraception is now being withdrawn (due to new research).

Comment: You're on the right track, but my hint perhaps gave an impression of an overly rigid answer format. I'll give you that the answer for #3 is "complaining about complaining about complaining," and also say that #1 is my favorite :)

Comment: I like your answer for #1, and consider it an adequate substitute for the "real" answer, which is (rot13) "n snvyher gb ercyvpngr n snvyher gb ercyvpngr n snvyher gb ercyvpngr." Only #2 would I still consider at-large, at this point.

Answer (score 2):

An attempt.

2:

> Skimming about skimming

3:

> Complaining about complaining about complaining

Which leads to the reasoning

> The answer are both the verb and the object

And so

1:

> Withdrawing / Pulling out. It is a historically discredited contraceptive, but also the act of reverting previous medical research opinion.

I'm not too sure about this so I'm going to leave another possible direction to think about Q1 so others can investigate:

> Abstinence / Abstention? I couldn't make sense of this word in the context of "vindicated by new research".

Answer (score 2):

I think we have:

What do you call it when a historically discredited means of contraceptive is vindicated by new research?

> A failure to replicate a failure to replicate a failure to replicate (per op)

I was just looking over my son's book report on speed reading strategies; what are you doing right now?

> (I am) reading about reading about reading.

What is this? The forums have been overwhelmed with hatemail after a dev criticized the tone of a negative review.

> (This is) complaining about complaining about complaining. (villasv/Ryan M) - 'complaints' also works equally well I think.

> So we have: Three answers with three repeated words!

Comment: Indeed, what I had in mind for #2 was "reading about reading about reading... about reading." The book report on speed reading is reading about reading; the speaker was reading about such; and now the puzzler was reading about that, hence the fourth reading. If you have no complaint, I'll go ahead and mark Ryan M the accepted answer since I believe he made the most individual progress. I may do another one of these in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

A different answer under different assumptions. I thought the answer for #2 by @ryan-m was great, but OP said it was the one among three needing improvement the most. So I'll have another go from a clean slate:

1.

> Negation of a negation of a negation

because

> The new study would be negating the negative view of the contraceptive

2. 

> overlooking an overlook on overlooking

because

> I'm overseeing someone taking a glance on a book about skimming

3. 

> Complaints about complaints about complaints

because

> The outcry from the developer reacting negatively to a complaint

I have to admit that I wouldn't have done it alone and without hints, but if this is it, it was pretty satisfying.

Answer (score -1):

1:

> Natural contraception.

Justification:

> I think so, because when an unknown problem occurred(if we consider ancient times), the simplest methods were used to solve it. Also, if we take into account historical data, we can draw the same conclusion as I did.

2:

> I'm reading.

Justification 1:

> The first explanation: if they ask what I am doing now, then it is logical to answer that I am reading at the moment.

Justification 2:

> The second explanation: if the riddle focuses on something, in this case on speed reading, then we can assume that the answer will be 'reading'.

Another version of the guess:

> The answer to all 3 riddles is the word 'science'.

Justification:

> 1. Refutation or confirmation of a statement is just science.
>    2. Reports, materials, or experiments are what constitutes science.
>    3. Refuting what has been proven by someone is also an element of science and at the same time, there may be negative comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these is actually correct. Although I will say, despite the downvote, you did hit upon *something*... More to come with the hint later today.

Comment: I will take note) there is another option.